# Python CSV data analysis based on date time

Tags: python, csv, datetime, dictionary, pandas

I have a large CSV file that we will be using to import assets into our asset management database. Here is a smaller example for the CSV data.

```
Serial number,Movement type,Posting date
2LMXK1,101,1/5/15 9:00
2LMXK1,102,1/5/15 9:30
2LMXK1,201,1/5/15 10:30
2LMXK1,202,1/5/15 13:00
2LMXK1,301,1/5/15 14:00
JEMLP3,101,1/6/15 9:00
JEMLP3,102,1/7/15 10:00
JEMLP3,201,1/7/15 13:30
JEMLP3,202,1/7/15 15:30
JEMLP3,203,1/7/15 17:30
BR83GP,101,1/5/15 9:00
BR83GP,102,1/5/15 13:00
BR83GP,201,1/6/15 9:00
BR83GP,202,1/7/15 15:30
BR83GP,301,1/5/15 13:00
BR83GP,201,1/6/15 9:00
BR83GP,301,1/9/15 15:30
```

Here are the requirements: “What is the LATEST movement type for each serial number?”

I need to parse the CSV file and for each UNIQUE serial number, take the movement type that has the LATEST “posting date”.

As an example, for Serial Number 2LMXK1 the latest posting date/time is 1/5/15 at 14:00.

Here is basically what I will need to obtain:

“Serial Number 2LMXK1 has a movement type 301 and was last updated 1/5/15 14:00”.

I have started with some code that parses the CSV file and creates a dictionary.

```
#Import modules
import csv
import pandas as pd

fields = ['Serial number','Movement type','Posting date']

df = pd.read_csv('import.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
dc = df.to_dict()

#print (df['Serial number'])

for value in dc.items():
    print (value)
```

This code works to parse the CSV and create a dictionary.

However, I need help with the date comparison and filtering techniques. How may I create another dictionary that only lists unique serial numbers with the latest posting date? Once I have created a new filtered data dictionary I can use that to import into our asset management database. The idea is that I will use python to analyze and manipulate the data before importing into our system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas is a useful library for more than just reading csv files. In fact, you don't need the csv library at all here (it's not being used in the code sample you posted)

First you need to make sure the dates are read in as dates, by using the `parse_dates` parameter of the `read_csv` function. Then you can use pandas' [grouping functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

```
# parse the 3rd column (index 2) as dates
df = pd.read_csv('import.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields, parse_dates=[2])
last_movement = df.sort_values('Posting date').groupby('Serial number').last()
```

To create the string that you want, you can then iterate through the rows of `last_movement`:

```
for index, row in last_movement.iterrows():
    print('Serial Number {} has a movement type {} and was last updated {}'
          .format(index, row['Movement type'], row['Posting date']))
```

Which will produce the following:

```
Serial Number 2LMXK1 has a movement type 301 and was last updated 2015-01-05 14:00:00
Serial Number BR83GP has a movement type 301 and was last updated 2015-01-09 15:30:00
Serial Number JEMLP3 has a movement type 203 and was last updated 2015-01-07 17:30:00
```

Side note: Pandas should be able to read the column headings for you, so you shouldn't need the `usecols` parameter

Comment: Great answer!! I don't think it can be done with less lines of code. It shall be noted that "sort_values" was added in pandas 0.17

Comment: @FrancescTorradeflot That's true. Earlier versions of pandas have a sort function that does the same thing, I think. The newer versions complain that that one is depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The dict creation or best way to sort the list depends a little on what you want but for the parsing side of things, to convert a string into a date object so you can then do sane comparisons etc you probably want the datetime module in datetime (yes, `datetime.datetime`)

It's got a strptime() function that will do exactly that:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(r"1/5/15 13:00", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
# I've assumed you have a Day/Month/Year format
```

The only bit of oddness is the format specifier, which is documented here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

(note that where it talks about zero-padded, that's for *output*. It'll parse non-zero padded numbers fine)